# Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 13 column 1 path $

Tags: java, android, gson, retrofit2

I saw this issue many times, but still can't understand. It looks like I send request on site and it's body isn't correct. But why? May be I don't understand clearly how retrofit works, but do not I just collect a link for the request and wait for the answer from the server?
Here is the link: [here](http://testwork.nsd.naumen.ru/rest/computers?p=2)

An interface with request

```
public interface NService {
    @GET("/computers?p=2")
    Call<Model> getItems();
}
```

and class with base URL

```
public class APIUtils {

    public static final String BASE_URL = "http://testwork.nsd.naumen.ru/rest/";

    public static NService getMService() {
        return RetrofitClient.getClient(BASE_URL).create(NService.class);
    }
}
```

retrofit build class

```
public class RetrofitClient {

    private static Retrofit retrofit = null;


    public static Retrofit getClient(String baseURL) {
        if (retrofit==null) {
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                    .setLenient()
                    .create();
            retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl(baseURL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                    .build();
        }
        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

JSON were parsed though [this](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)

and MainActivity is:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private List<Item> responseModel;
    private NService mService;
    private TextView textView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.d("testcrap", "before loading set");
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mService = APIUtils.getMService(); // Строим retrofit объект, собираем ссылку
        Log.d("testcrap", "before loading");
        loadSomeCrap();
        Log.d("testcrap", "after loading");
    }

    public void loadSomeCrap() {
        Log.d("testcrap", "started parsing");
        mService.getItems().enqueue(new Callback<Model>() {

            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Model> call, Response<Model> response) {
                Log.d("testcrap", "started onResponse");

                if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                    Log.d("testcrap", "posts loaded from API");
                }else {
                    Log.d("testcrap", "posts not loaded from API");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Model> call, Throwable t) {
                //showErrorMes  sage();
                Log.d("testcrap", t.toString());

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Log:

```
before loading set
before loading
started parsing
after loading
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 13 column 1 path $
```

So, if it's wrong request, what should I change for normal work?

Comment: Issues in you model class please past model class so i can help out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make these changes ..

```
BASE_URL = "http://testwork.nsd.naumen.ru/"
```

And then on interface ..

```
@GET("rest/computers?p=2")
.............
```

Answer (score 0):

Your API or JSON response is returning JSON_OBJECT but you are getting it in String so this JsonSyntaxException is shown you. Try to fetch response in OBJECT.